# A View with an ObservedObject and nothing will allow me to edit it

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

https://github.com/ryanpeach/RoutinesAppiOS

A Picker will not move, the Edit Button won't click, and a Text Field won't enter more than 1 character. Return on keyboard doesn't work. Most of these are tied to bindings to the ObservedObject and should be able to directly edit it. I believe there is a common cause with CoreData hanging on object updates. The done button on the final player view hangs, but the skip button does not! That means it only happens when TaskData is updated. If you delete an Alarm in certain situations the app crashes too.

Here's a video of the app behavior so far. In the view right before the end nothing will click. At the final view it hangs when you click the checkmark.

https://www.icloud.com/photos/#0HMiYqZ08ZYoFu5BEQXET4gRA

I am seeking some tips on how to debug this error. I can't put a breakpoint on the picker "when something changes" and I similarly cant do it on the Text Field. Why would a text field only take one character and then stop? Why would the edit button not work? This is the only view in the app where these sub-views don't work, the rest of the app works fine.

Some relevant background information:

I'm using coredata. There are 3 classes: AlarmData for the Routines Page, which has a one2many relationship to TaskData for the TaskList Page, which has a one2many relationship to SubTaskData for the TaskPlayerView and TaskEditor pages, the ones I'm having trouble with.

No further relationships.

I'm doing a fetchrequest at the root view and then using @ObservedObject the rest of the way down the view hierarchy. I'm using mostly isActive and tag:selection NavigationLinks.

The relevant file:

```swift
struct TaskEditorView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @ObservedObject var taskData: TaskData
    @State var newSubTask: String = ""

    var subTaskDataList: [SubTaskData] {
        var out: [SubTaskData] = []
        for sub_td in self.taskData.subTaskDataList {
           out.append(sub_td)
       }
       return out
   }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TitleTextField(text: self.$taskData.name)
            Spacer().frame(height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT_SPACING)
            TimePickerRelativeView(time: self.$taskData.duration)
            Spacer().frame(height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT_SPACING)
            HStack {
                Spacer().frame(width: DEFAULT_LEFT_ALIGN_SPACE, height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT_SPACING)
                ReturnTextField(
                    label: "New Subtask",
                    text: self.$newSubTask,
                    onCommit: self.addSubTask
                )
                Button(action: {
                    self.addSubTask()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .frame(width: DEFAULT_LEFT_ALIGN_SPACE, height: 30)
                }
                Spacer().frame(width: DEFAULT_HEIGHT_SPACING)
            }
            Spacer().frame(height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT_SPACING)
            Text("Subtasks:")
            Spacer().frame(height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT_SPACING)
            List {
                ForEach(self.subTaskDataList, id: \.id) { sub_td in
                    Text(sub_td.name)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: self.delete)
                .onMove(perform: self.move)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }

    ...

}
```

It also doesn't like to be edited here (see FLAG comment):

```swift
struct TaskPlayerView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    var taskDataList: [TaskData] {
        return self.alarmData.taskDataList
    }

    var taskData: TaskData {
        return self.taskDataList[self.taskIdx]
    }

    var subTaskDataList: [SubTaskData] {
        var out: [SubTaskData] = []
        for sub_td in self.taskData.subTaskDataList {
            out.append(sub_td)
        }
        return out
    }

    @ObservedObject var alarmData: AlarmData
    @State var taskIdx: Int = 0

    // For the timer
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var isPlay: Bool = true
    @State var done: Bool = false
    @State var startTime: Date?
    @State var lastTime: Date = Date()
    @State var durationBeforePause: TimeInterval = 0
    @State var durationSoFar: TimeInterval = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !self.done {
                ...
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            if self.subTaskDataList.count == 0 || self.subTaskDataList.allSatisfy({$0.done}) {
                                // FLAG: It fails here where setting task data
                                self.taskData.lastDuration_ = self.durationSoFar
                                self.taskData.done = true
                                self.taskData.lastEdited = Date()
                                self.next()
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        if self.subTaskDataList.count == 0 || self.subTaskDataList.allSatisfy({$0.done}) {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
           ...
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```